# Install SVN on server on line without SSH access

Tags: php, svn, ssh, git-svn

I have a question about my project and SVN!I'm using OVH "Hosting Personal"(hébérgement mutualisé perso),so I do not have access SSH,and I can't install SVN directly on my OVH server...

I wish to install SVN on remote OVH server without SSH access.I tried to find a solution to install SVN on my local server(OS: Ubuntu,apache2) and put My Project inside and then I download all installation of SVN with configuration files to my server OVH on line,is that it is possible?

I hope to put my project on line and make modification and checkout when I wan't,but all tutorials talks just to do it with SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: you probably can't.

<strike>Even if you had an SSH access, I guess that on shared hosting, OVH doesn't give you access to svn tools, and doesn't let you install svn.</strike>

Edit: [this guide on OVH](http://guides.ovh.com/SVNMutu) (in french) indicates it is possible to use svn, and that the only condition to use it is to have SSH access

PS: you don't have a server: you have some disk space on a server: big difference !

Comment: Edited my answer: it is possible to use SVN on shared hosting, if you have an SSH access, but only if you have it...

Answer (score 0):

If it was technically possible, it would anyway most likely be a breach to OVH service terms of use.

[Here is a link the the French "Conditions d'utilisation"](http://www.ovh.com/fr/support/documents_legaux/conditions%20particulieres%20hebergement%20mutualise.pdf), in case you need to know what's inside :)

Only the use of PHP/CGI scripts is allowed, and with load restrictions.